# $X$th digit from end of $(111\dots)^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How do we find the $73$rd digit from ending of $(111111\dots 1)^2$ where ones are repeated $2012$?

Comment: From near the middle onwards you get repeats of 987654320 until the final 987654321. The 73rd digit from the end is the last digit of one of these groups, so it is a 0.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with long multiplication.

> > ....11111
> >     +...11110
> >     +...11100
> >     +...11000
> >     +...10000

and so on.  The units digits is 1, the tens digit is 2, and the hundreds digit is 3.
When you get to the tenth digit, you start having to carry.

Good luck.